# wordpress issue with enqueueing script into plugin

Tags: wordpress

Below code is for enqueueing js/css into my pluign file.

there is a problem with enqueueing wpautocomplete.js and not attaching the below code

but if i remove array('jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery') from

```
    wp_register_script( 'wpautocomplete', PLUGIN_URL. '/include/js/wpautocomplete.js', array('jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

it works and enqueues wpautocomplete.js into my plugin but autocomplete function inside js is not working.

can anyone guide me did I make mistake with the enqueue order js in below code?

```
    wp_register_style( "bootstrap", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/css/bootstrap.min.css',false); 
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
    wp_register_style( "bootstrap-theme", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/css/bootstrap-theme.css',false); 
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-theme');
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-styles',PLUGIN_URL.'/include/css/jquery-ui.css' );    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-styles' );
    wp_deregister_script("jquery");
    wp_deregister_script("jquery-ui-autocomplete");
    wp_register_script( "jquery", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/jquery-1.12.4.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );      
    wp_register_script( "jquery-ui", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/jquery-ui.js',false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );                   
    wp_register_script( "custom", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/custom.js',false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );  
    wp_localize_script( 'wpautocomplete', 'autocompletefunction', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wpautocomplete-nonce' )) );
    wp_register_script( 'wpautocomplete', PLUGIN_URL. '/include/js/wpautocomplete.js', array('jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery'), '1.0.0', true );                           
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpautocomplete' );

    wp_register_script( "bootstrap", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/bootstrap.min.js',false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook

Here is an example:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( "bootstrap", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/css/bootstrap.min.css',false); 
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
    wp_register_style( "bootstrap-theme", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/css/bootstrap-theme.css',false); 
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-theme');
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-styles',PLUGIN_URL.'/include/css/jquery-ui.css' );    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-styles' );
    wp_deregister_script("jquery");
    wp_deregister_script("jquery-ui-autocomplete");
    wp_register_script( "jquery", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/jquery-1.12.4.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );      
    wp_register_script( "jquery-ui", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/jquery-ui.js',false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );                   
    wp_register_script( "custom", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/custom.js',false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );  
    wp_localize_script( 'wpautocomplete', 'autocompletefunction', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wpautocomplete-nonce' )) );
    wp_register_script( 'wpautocomplete', PLUGIN_URL. '/include/js/wpautocomplete.js', array('jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery'), '1.0.0', true );                           
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpautocomplete' );

    wp_register_script( "bootstrap", PLUGIN_URL.'/include/js/bootstrap.min.js',false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i have already used action hook for admin_enqueue_script. i just posted scripts and their orders in my question.